# Installed script, deleted everything in public html, getting a 500 internal error ever since

Tags: php, web, internal

I installed a browser game called travian on my webhosting under the domain of freetravian.com

it didn't go smoothly so i deleted everything in public html and started over, in the middle of installation I get this error

Internal Server Error

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration
```

and was unable to complete your request.

```
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@freetravian.com
```

and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might 
have done that may have caused the error.

```
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
```

use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I filed a ticket and they have tried to fixed it buy haven't done so in three days. So I decided to ask members on stack overflow.

The message says to check error logs, so I did that.

```
[Sat Jun 16 17:05:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml
[Sat Jun 16 17:05:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/favicon.ico
[Sat Jun 16 17:05:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/500.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=3
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:52 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:52 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/favicon.ico
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:51 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=3
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:51 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/img, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=3
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:51 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=3
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:51 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/new.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=3
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:51 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=3
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:51 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/unx.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=3
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:51 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=3
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:51 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/mt-full.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=3
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:42 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:42 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/favicon.ico
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=2
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/img, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=2
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=2
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/new.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=2
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=2
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/unx.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=2
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=2
[Sat Jun 16 17:04:41 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/mt-full.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/index.php?s=2
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:04 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:04 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/favicon.ico
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:03 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/?s=1
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:03 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/img, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/?s=1
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:03 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/?s=1
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:03 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/new.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/?s=1
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:03 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/?s=1
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:03 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/unx.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/?s=1
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:03 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/?s=1
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:03 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/mt-full.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/?s=1
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:01 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml
[Sat Jun 16 17:02:01 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/favicon.ico
[Sat Jun 16 17:01:56 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/
[Sat Jun 16 17:01:56 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/img, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/
[Sat Jun 16 17:01:56 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/
[Sat Jun 16 17:01:56 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/new.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/
[Sat Jun 16 17:01:56 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/
[Sat Jun 16 17:01:56 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/unx.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/
[Sat Jun 16 17:01:55 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/
[Sat Jun 16 17:01:55 2012] [error] [client 75.95.232.155] File does not exist: /home/freetrav/public_html/travian/install/mt-full.js, referer: http://www.freetravian.com/travian/install/
```

What could possibly be the cause? i suspect i deleted something important in public html.
I'll +1 everyone who answers. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a vhost site. What does the configuration for it look like?

Comment: I don't even know what this 'configuration' is. is it some kind of a file? what is it called? also i was reading google results and it said this could happen to files permissions.
i was setting everything to 777, could this effect it?

Comment: Well assuming you're on shared hosting, you probably don't have to bother with any of that. Have you tried putting a blank index file in your `public_html` and seeing if you could request it?

Comment: some files do work, for example, the server support people put index.html file in freetravian.com, that file works

Comment: Then everything should be fine. You can upload the files you need to into your `public_html` and everything should work fine.

Comment: i'm trying to install a script, and when i do so, i sometimes get a 500 error.

Comment: during installation. maybe its because some files need to be changed to 777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are your Apache error logs I believe, I think you need to look at your PHP error logs to get to the proper error.

Comment: how can i find them in cpanel?